# What are relative paths relative to?

Tags: c#

Consider the following statement in a C# console application:

```
Process.Start("3rdParty/SomeTool.exe");
```

This statement starts `SomeTool.exe` in the `3rdParty` folder relative to... what, exactly? The folder where the application's .exe resides? The current working directory (which can be changed during the application's lifetime)? Something else?

Comment: relative to work directory.

Comment: [More information about paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why don't we find out?

Let's create a simple console application and have some fun with it:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("Test");
            Console.WriteLine($"Absolute path is: { Path.GetFullPath("Test")}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
 }
```

Build it in release mode (we are deploying it after all) and put it in some accesible location. Now double click on it and see what output you get.

> Absolute path is: {SomeAccesibleLocationPath}\Test

Hmmm, it seems like the relative path is relative to the directory where the executable was launched. Is this always so?

Let's build another app, we'll call it ConsoleApplication2, and play some more:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"TEST #1: {LaunchProcessAndGetAbsolutePath()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"TEST #2: {LaunchProcessAndGetAbsolutePath(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments))}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string LaunchProcessAndGetAbsolutePath(string workingDirectory = null)
    {
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"{SomeAccesibleLocationPath}\ConsoleApplication1.exe");
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        if (workingDirectory != null)
        {
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
        }

        using (var p = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            var ret = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine();
            p.WaitForExit();
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

If we run this, you'll see that the output is the following:

> TEST #1: {MyConsoleApplication2ExecutableDirectory}\Test
>
> TEST #2: {MyDocumentsPath}\Test

Important facts to consider:

1. The relative paths are always relative to the working directory.
2. When starting a process from another process, the default working directory is the working directory of the "parent" process, its *not* the directory of the launched "child" process.
3. When launching a process by double clicking on the executable, the working directory is set to the executable's directory.
4. In general, the working directory need not be the executable's directory. Your program's correctness should not rely on this condition ever.

Comment: Thank you for a very informative answer! Both what I *wanted* to know and what I *needed* to know but hadn't considered.

Answer (score 6):

It is relative to the current working directory of your process.

You can determine your current working directory using [`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory) and change it using [`Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, it is relative to the current working directory. The value can be changed and determined via `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()`, resp. `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

*Some notes:*

The current working directory **CAN** be the folder where the executable resides; this is the default working directory if none is specified. **But** it can also be set to a different folder when a process is started or while running. On start either by setting the property `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory` when launching a process, or also by using the working directory field in the symbolic link dialog in e.g. the start menu. The latter can be done by a user. The current working directory **CAN** also be changed by any 3rd party library that is being loaded into the process.

Therefore relative paths in an application without checking the working directory are **unreliable** and usually cause unexpected behavior.